# The system time interval between Arm and Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

**Problem Description**: With Arm machine as a Server, with Ubuntu as a Client, Server via the Client send time package to sync that time, after synced time, Comparing their time, I found that with a continuation of the time, the time difference is bigger and bigger, I suspect that may be Arm machines and the Client's clock is not consistent, Coule you help me with this? Thanks.

**Test Environment**:
Arm machine: zcu104 development board, with the soc on top is Zynq UltraScale+MPSoC xczu7ev-2ffvc1156.

Client machine: the normal Ubuntu system, we used three Ubuntu system machines, test many times can reproduce this phenomenon.

At the same time, the test adopts the direct connection mode of the machine, which can basically ignore the interference of network problems, so the test results are credible.

**Sync Time Func**:

gettimeofday()

settimeofday()

**Post the results and the environment:**

value is in milliseconds

print every 6s

diff- -1
diff- -1
diff- 0
diff- -1
diff- 0
diff- 0
diff- 1
diff- 1
diff- 2
diff- 3
diff- 2
diff- 2
diff- 4
diff- 4
diff- 5
diff- 5
diff- 5
diff- 5
diff- 6
diff- 7
diff- 7
diff- 6
diff- 7
diff- 7
diff- 7
diff- 8
diff- 8
diff- 9
diff- 9
diff- 10
diff- 10
diff- 10
diff- 10
diff- 12
diff- 12
diff- 12
diff- 12
diff- 12
diff- 13
diff- 13
diff- 14
diff- 14
diff- 15
diff- 15
diff- 15
diff- 15
diff- 16
diff- 16
diff- 16
diff- 17
diff- 17
diff- 18
diff- 18
diff- 18
diff- 18
diff- 19
diff- 19
diff- 20
diff- 21
diff- 21
diff- 21
diff- 21
diff- 22
diff- 22
diff- 23
diff- 23
diff- 23

Ubuntu cpu(Twelve processors):
uname -a:Linux ITSK-20190401KK 4.4.0-17763-Microsoft #379-Microsoft Wed Mar 06 19:16:00 PST 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
cat /proc/cpuinfo:
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700 CPU @ 3.20GHz
stepping        : 10
microcode       : 0xffffffff
cpu MHz         : 3192.000
cache size      : 256 KB

Arm cpu(Four processors):
cat /proc/cpuinfo has not useful output
uname -a:Linux xilinx-zcu104-2018_3 4.14.0-xilinx-v2018.3 #65 SMP Mon May 13 21:25:05 CST 2019 aarch64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Not clear what is the time reference. The Ubuntu machines' clock are normally sync'ed to some time server using systemd-timesyncd. If the ARM machine isn't sync'ed then there will be discrepancies. If you try to set the time on the Ubuntu machine from the ARM without disabling the existing Ubuntu autosync this won't last long. But no point setting an accurate clock (Ubuntu) to a imprecise clock (ARM)? Normally either the ARM is sync'ed to some external source (and so will be coherent with the Ubuntu machines) or is sync'ed using the Ubuntu machines as reference.

Comment: Thanks, I get struct timeval from gettimeofday function in Ubuntu, and use this struct to call settimeofday in Arm to sync Arm's time.And then compare the time between the two sides used gettimeofday function, Finding the time difference getting bigger and bigger.

Comment: Well the NTP protocol is more complex than this, because its takes in consideration the time to transfer the information. IMHO you should set up the ARM with a NTP client that ither use standard NTP servers or use one of your Ubuntu with a suitable NTP server.